# Knowledge lost - font unknown

Tags: font-identification

As we want to reprint our old T-Shirts from the student representatives, but we have to change something - and we don't know anymore the font, which was used.

No automatic service was able to detect the font, especially the y does not match.

The font looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no exact matches among the hundreds presented amongst the handwriting fonts at [MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/tag%3Ahandwriting/fonts/) but one possibility might be [FG Abby](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontgarden/fg-abby/). There are a number of reasonable matches; I think this is the closest. You might find another you prefer more.

[image: FG Abby]

You may need *either* to take the opportunity to produce a "Second Edition", *or* to use the artwork you uploaded to the question.

Comment: Seems to me it could also simply be hand-drawn, and not a font as such. The match Andrew found is impressively close though. If Andrew gave you the answer you needed, please click "accept answer" - this is good for you, him and all the rest of us.

Comment: Yes, that's true - might be hand-drawn. We now found an alternative, thanks for your help :-)